# Error clicking object in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Error clicking on any object in the left pane. Strangely I can perform SQL queries, but not display any object. This happens in version 4.1.1.19 and in an Oracle 9i data.

[image]

Comment: Is SQL Developer 4 even usable on 9i?  That database has been out of support for 10 years or more.

Comment: there any way to use a previous JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a version of SQLDeveloper that will work with Oracle 9i [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev30downloads-1525485.html).  Be sure you get the one with the JDK as newer JDK's that are installed should work but might not.

Comment: This is the issue, you're using a 12c JDBC driver against an 9i database that doesn't understand the JDBC calls. Use an older version of SQLDev, or upgrade your database, or try a thick connection in 4.1 with an 11gr2 client to see if that helps.